# Wirelessly connect two wifi ADSL routers with manual settings

Tags: wireless-networking

My two wifi ADSL routers don't have any advanced features (no "bridge mode" setting, and the WDS functionality doesn't seem to work), I'd like to connect them to each other wirelessly to extend the range of the network. One of the routers is connected to ADSL.

So far I have put the same settings on both routers, the ssid, channel, encryption type and key.

I can't ping the internet connected router from a computer connected to the second wifi router.

Is it possible to get this setup working?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any "bridging" mode, and the second can't be configured as an AP Client (and even then this won't extend your wifi range), the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible with the equipment you have. as neither device will attempt connecting to a wireless network as booth where made to be the one in charge of it. with the addition some device to act as a wireless bridge you could jury-rig something but you'd have to make sure that bridge connects only to the "root ap" to pull it off.  and the main problem there is that a cheap standalone wi-fi bridge is about the same price as a cheap wi-fi repeater so might as well just get the part you need and save yourself the hassle.